# How to obtain present "standard time" from my fortran code for a specific time zone

Tags: fortran, clock

I am running a numerical model on my laptop that does a real time forecast for Italy. I noticed I have a small bug: I check if I received on my laptop some data from some stations (that are sent to me at midnight Italy standard time), and if after N hours I did not receive a particular data, I run the simulation anyway issuing a warning. N is usually 5 hours, but can be changed from input file. Now the problem is: I use the fortran call:

```
    call date_and_time(date=clock_date, &  ! character(len=8)  ccyymmdd 
                       time=clock_time)    ! character(len=10) hhmmss.sss
```

that works fine, but it gives me the daylight saving times, while the time I receive the data and all my simulations are in standard time. Moreover, since I am travelling very often, if I am in USA the time that is read is totally wrong. Is there any way to get the standard time for a particular time zone? Since in the future after testing it I will move the code to a desktop pc (running windows) in Italy, it would be enough to have the standard time from that computer. As a last resort if that is not possible, is there a way to Syncronize the clock of the computer to a server proving the standard time?

thanks.
A.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`date_and_time` has an additional argument called `zone`. See the manual

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/DATE_005fAND_005fTIME.html

The code

```
  character(len=8)  clock_date 
  character(len=10) clock_time
  character(5) zone
  call date_and_time(date=clock_date, &  ! character(len=8)  ccyymmdd 
                     time=clock_time, &    ! character(len=10) hhmmss.sss 
                     zone=zone)  

  print *,clock_date
  print *,clock_time
  print *,zone
end
```

prints

```
 20141018
 112233.644
 +0200
```

You can easily use that `+0200` to subtract those 2 hours from the indicated time to get the UTC time. You can also use the values of the array `values, as High Performance Mark points out. Don't forget to adjust the date if you cross midnight.

Comment: Thanks that solves the problem. But I can in general cross midnight and change year or month...so I have to write a subroutine that sums or subtract a value between -24 and 24 to clock_date and take in account of leap years, not that hard but still some extra work...

Comment: You could also use a Fortran wrapper around the `GetSystemTime` function of Windows. I use such a solution on Linux.

Answer (score 4):

To add to what @VladimirF has already written `date_and_time` can take yet another optional `intent(out)` argument, `values`, which is an integer array of 8 elements.  If used, upon return from a call `values(4)` reports the offset, in minutes, from UTC of the local time, or `-huge(0)` if that is not available.  The other elements of `values` return the other components of a date and time as integers, to save messing around with conversions from strings.

Comment: Ops, I of course new about `values`, but I missed that particular field, because I expected it to be at the and of the array.